# When should users add a name to newly created items? Or is automatic naming sufficient?

Tags: usability, interaction-design, user-behavior

[image]I'm building a platform for building widget that you can integrate in your website. For each widget, you need a name. However, I'm not sure you I should ask a user to create a name in the very beginning.

You know, it's like buidling a video on an editing platfrom when you don't really care about the name of the video.

My assumption is user doesn't care about the name, and each widget can automatically be given a name, and then a user can modify it if they want to.

What do you think? ask to create name in the start of the flow? create some default name automatically? I'm confused.

Comment: Agree with SylvainBTL's answer but check in with your engineers. There might be a technical reason to make this happen first.

Answer (score 1):

You can guide the user to perform required steps, including naming the new element. Otherwise, you end up with things like Adobe or Google apps (between many others) where you have "Untitled Doc Document", "Untitled Document 2", "Untitled Document *N*" (replace "Document" with " Sheet" or any app). The only way to find out what's in those documents is to open them and review them (and usually rename them so you don't have to do that again).

Instead, I'd suggest using a default placeholder name (widget-1, 2, 3, *n*), but at the time of saving the widget, if no name has been added, a dialog box with information like **"This widget doesn't have a name, adding a name will make it easier to find"** and then an option like **"Save anyway"** to support [**locus of control**](https://www.ics.com/blog/eight-golden-rules-rule-7-support-internal-locus-control) (assuming that the user doesn't care, it's his/her prerogative).

Answer (score 0):

create some default name automatically like Untitled widget, Untitled widget 1 and more with edit option

Time-saving: Default names allow users to quickly create items without having to spend time finding an appropriate name from the outset. This allows them to focus on other aspects of creation.

Encouraging editing: Generic names draw users' attention and encourage them to edit and customize them later to make them more descriptive.

Preventing confusion: By adding a sequential number to default names (e.g., "Untitled widget 1", "Untitled widget 2"), you help users distinguish newly created items from others, even if they haven't been renamed yet.

Flexibility: The edit option allows users to rename their widgets at any time, according to their needs and preferences. This gives them full control over item management and organization.

Fewer errors: By using default names, you prevent users from accidentally leaving items unnamed, which could lead to errors or confusion later on.

In summary, using default names with an edit option improves the user experience by providing a quick and efficient way to create items while encouraging proper customization and organization.

Comment: Can you elaborate why you think this is the best solution for the user? Is there proof perhaps that can substantiate this?

Comment: i update my post @jazZRo

Answer (score 0):

Figma provides a useful reference — widgets (frames, groups, shapes etc.) are automatically named, and serialized when possible. The UI gets out of the way and let me get the job done. As a user, I edit widget names when they are of "sufficient" importance to me. Your platform's users may like a similar approach.